# Collection view index out of range when using refresher

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, collectionview

I'm loading an array of images into a `CollectionView`.

When I activate the refresher, I'm calling this method:

```
func fetchPics(){
        //Clear array of post
        pics?.removeAll()

            Common.sharedInstance.fetchPics(completion: { (pics) in
            self.pics = pics
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            self.refresher.endRefreshing()
        })
    }
```

The `viewDidLoad` of the view controller calls this method and everything loads fine; however, calling it from the refresher gives me a:

```
fatal error: Index out of range
```

Error in :

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: postCellId, for: indexPath) as! PicCell

        //This is the line that gives me the error
        cell.pic = pics?[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item]

        return cell
    }
```

What's the appropriate way of reloading the collection view without getting this error?

Thank you

Comment: try `cell.pic = pics?[indexPath.row]` and see if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I was calling a shared instance of a class in which I make the database calls.. In that class I had created an instance of a pics array in which I was then returning through the completion block.

I wasn't calling the `pics?.removeAll` inside of the fetchPics method so it was appending to it every time.

Thank you guys for the guidance leading to this answer

Answer (score 3):

Try to put `pics?.removeAll()` also inside the completion block because your closure code will execute later and if your `collectionView` might be call `cellForItemAt indexPath` the you are getting empty array.

```
 func fetchPics(){

    Common.sharedInstance.fetchPics(completion: { (pics) in

        pics?.removeAll()
        self.pics = pics
        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
        self.refresher.endRefreshing()
    })
}
```

**Note :** If you doesn't call `removeAll` that will also work as of you are initializing the array again with new value.

Comment: I tried adding it inside and now it's appending to the pics array instead of reloading it. Like it adds the content to what's already there as if remove all wasn't even there. @NiravD

Comment: @Walker I'm talking about completion block not about the method `fetchPics`, so if you remove `pics?.removeAll()` from completion block it will still work i havn't told about your `fetchPics` method read the answer again.

Comment: I posted the answer below 20 minutes ago. Thank you for help